# Automatic recompilation: if a CMake client project depends on a separate CMake library, how to have the client project re build its dependency?

Tags: cmake, libraries

With a growing codebase, it makes sense to organize it between separate repositories, each repo being a separate CMake-managed project.

Because of modularity, this usually means you end up in a situation where a CMake-managed project *Application* depends on another CMake-managed project *Library*, while both are internal code (i.e., code owned and maintained by your structure).

### The automatic dependency recompilation issue

Then, if some sources in *Library* are modified, it needs to be recompiled in order to build *Application*. The question being:

Is it possible to have the "build *Application*" command (a button in an IDE, or a call to `make` on the command line) to first rebuild *Library* if *Library* files changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at how the [**OpenChemistry** parent-project](https://github.com/OpenChemistry/openchemistry) does it, and with the confirmation by **normanius**'s answer, it turns out this can be achieved with relatively few CMake script code.

It turns out that CMake CLI is offering an abstraction over the "build" action of the targeted build systems. See [--build option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html#options).
`ExternalProject_Add` can be seen as a wrapper to use this CLI interface directly from CMake scripts.

---

Imagine there is a CMake-managed repository, building *libuseful*, and a separate CMake-managed repo, building *appawesome* with a dependency on *libuseful*.

```
find_package(libuseful CONFIG) # The usual way to find a dependency

# appawesome is the executable we are building, it depends on libuseful
add_executable(appawesome main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(appawesome libuseful)
```

### Adding automatic rebuild

Then it is possible to make building *appawesome* systematically first try to rebuild *libuseful* with some code looking like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(EP_libuseful)
    SOURCE_DIR <libuseful_sourcedir>  # containing libuseful's root CMakeLists.txt
    BINARY_DIR <libuseful_binarydir>  # containing libuseful's CMakeCache.txt
    BUILD_ALWAYS 1                    # Always rebuild libuseful
)

add_dependencies(libuseful EP_libuseful)
```

The last line is quite important: `find_package()` in config mode should make a *libuseful* imported targed available. The call to `ExternalProject_Add` made a build target `EP_libuseful` available (which is a custom build step, building *libuseful*). The last line just makes sure that *libuseful* depends on its build step.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use the `ExternalProject_Add` command.

The documentation has slightly changed for the different versions:

- [CMake v2.8.9 ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#module:ExternalProject)
- [CMake v3.0. ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=externalproject)
- [CMake v3.3 ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=externalproject)

In case you encounter problems with getting the dependencies right, [this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-October/047001.html) thread might help you.